# Add custom link to operations in 'admin/content'

Tags: drupal-7

Can someone give me a suggestion on how to add another link to the "operations"-cell on admin/node?

I have written a module which copies a specific node and now i need in addition to the links "edit" and "delete" a "copy"-link.

Can´t find any useful hints in the Drupal API.

Comment: you mean to the operations column on admin/content?  There is no admin/node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "admin/node" you actually mean "admin/content/node", I think you're looking for hook_node_operations().

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_operations/7

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to download [admin_menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module. It contains administration views (you also need to enable it in Modules), which changes default content grid to the custom view. You can then go to Views and modify the admin/content view as you want.